# How can I add image titles to the active item in the jQuery ImageViewer plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

Generally I depend on prebuilt Javascript and Jquery as it satisfies my interface needs (I am more comfortable with databases). In this case I have plugged http://ignitersworld.com/lab/imageViewer.html using 'container mode' into my site and am quite happy. However, I would like to add one thing that I don't know how to modify in Javascript.

In the `container mode` one sees a `current image number` / `total image number`.

The javascript (see bottom of post) sets the values for the spans in this HTML:

```
<div id="image-gallery-2">
  <div class="image-container"></div>
  <img src="assets/images/left.svg" class="prev"/>
  <img src="assets/images/right.svg"  class="next"/>
  <div class="footer-info">
    <span class="current"></span>/<span class="total"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to add single word title for each image beside these spans that is shown against its respective image. It's trivial for me to dynamically load these to the HTML at the same time as I generate the list of images.

For example, I could dump out a list of spans where the 'id' of each span matches the name of the pictures 'loaded' by Javascript, to begin to create a tie of some sort:

```
<span class="imgttle" id="1.jpg">Title</span>
<span class="imgttle" id="2.jpg">Title</span>
<span class="imgttle" id="3.jpg">Title</span>
<span class="imgttle" id="4.jpg">Title</span>
```

Or, as I already dynamically create the javascript function with the respective image links, I can also output javascript var with the titles.

But I haven't a clue how to get these to show/hide and synchronise with prev/next clicks in the javascript below.

```
$(function () {
 var images = [{
    small : 'assets/images/image_viewer/1.jpg',
    big : 'assets/images/image_viewer/1_big.jpg'
 },{
    small : 'assets/images/image_viewer/2.jpg',
    big : 'assets/images/image_viewer/2_big.jpg'
 },{
    small : 'assets/images/image_viewer/3.jpg',
    big : 'assets/images/image_viewer/3_big.jpg'
 },{
    small : 'assets/images/image_viewer/4.jpg',
    big : 'assets/images/image_viewer/4_big.jpg'
 }];

 var curImageIdx = 1,
    total = images.length;
 var wrapper = $('#image-gallery-2'),
    curSpan = wrapper.find('.current');
 var viewer = ImageViewer(wrapper.find('.image-container'));

 //display total count
 wrapper.find('.total').html(total);

 function showImage(){
    var imgObj = images[curImageIdx - 1];
    viewer.load(imgObj.small, imgObj.big);
    curSpan.html(curImageIdx);
 }

 wrapper.find('.next').click(function(){
     curImageIdx++;
    if(curImageIdx > total) curImageIdx = 1;
    showImage();
 });

 wrapper.find('.prev').click(function(){
     curImageIdx--;
    if(curImageIdx < 0) curImageIdx = total;
    showImage();
 });

 //initially show image
 showImage();
});
```

Thanks very much in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Can you pass your titles on the `img` elements as `title`  or data attributes? That might simplify things.

Comment: BTW, there are four zillion jQuery plugins that will do this out of the box. I realize it's painful to back out of your effort, but....

Comment: Ah, of course - I didn't think about that, but yes I could put the titles in the img element. It still leaves me with the js problem :)

Comment: Well, I was looking to balance time to adjust this versus configuring something new. This has the benefit of teaching me a bit about javascript.  But if you recommend another plug-in that matches fit, finish and zoom of this, and ease of configuration, I'm open to switching it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
  var images = [{
    small: 'https://ignitersworld.com/lab/assets/images/image_viewer/1.jpg',
    big: 'https://ignitersworld.com/lab/assets/images/image_viewer/1_big.jpg',
    title: 'one' // < ------- changes here
  }, {
    small: 'https://ignitersworld.com/lab/assets/images/image_viewer/2.jpg',
    big: 'https://ignitersworld.com/lab/assets/images/image_viewer/2_big.jpg',
    title: 'two' // < ------- changes here
  }, {
    small: 'https://ignitersworld.com/lab/assets/images/image_viewer/3.jpg',
    big: 'https://ignitersworld.com/lab/assets/images/image_viewer/3_big.jpg',
    title: 'three' // < ------- changes here
  }, {
    small: 'https://ignitersworld.com/lab/assets/images/image_viewer/4.jpg',
    big: 'https://ignitersworld.com/lab/assets/images/image_viewer/4_big.jpg',
    title: 'four' // < ------- changes here
  }];

  var curImageIdx = 1,
    total = images.length,
    wrapper = $('#image-gallery'),
    curSpan = wrapper.find('.current'),
    titleSpan = wrapper.find('.title'), // < ------- changes here
    viewer = ImageViewer(wrapper.find('.image-container'));

  //display total count
  wrapper.find('.total').html(total);

  function showImage() {
    var imgObj = images[curImageIdx - 1];
    viewer.load(imgObj.small, imgObj.big, imgObj.title); // < ------- changes here
    curSpan.html(curImageIdx);
    titleSpan.html(imgObj.title); // < ------- changes here
  }

  wrapper.find('.next').click(function() {
    curImageIdx++;
    if (curImageIdx > total) curImageIdx = 1;
    showImage();
  });

  wrapper.find('.prev').click(function() {
    curImageIdx--;
    if (curImageIdx < 0) curImageIdx = total;
    showImage();
  });

  //initially show image
  showImage();
});
```

**[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/xfmv28nj/)**

Comment: Thanks for this, works great and I really appreciate the effort. And it really helps me understanding the innerworkings.